# Factorization of the public value $N$ from the RSA cryptosystem

Tags: rsa, factoring

It is mentioned [here](https://blog.trailofbits.com/2019/07/08/fuck-rsa/) that the public value $N=p*q$ of the RSA cryptosystem can be factorized if one of the factors is reused. Thus, if $N_1=p*q_1$ and $N_2=p*q_2$ and only $N_1$ and $N_2$ are known, then one can factor $N_1$ and $N_2$.

I wasn't able to come up how this can be achieved. Is that statement really true?

Answer (score 2):

Since $p$ is a factor in both $N_1$ and $N_2$ you can simply calculate $p$ by using [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Once you have $p$ you can then calculate $q_1$ and $q_2$ (simply divide $N_1$ by $p$ to get $q_1$ and divide $N_2$ by $p$ to get $q_2$).